# Want to take off the border of the infragistics textbox 

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, textbox, infragistics

I have a **infragistics textbox**. I want to remove its border. and I am not sure how to do it?

```
this._myTextTextBox.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.None;
```

This is what i thought should work fine for me, but its not giving any fruitful result.

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this question to the company which made this software. How can we know about the properties of this company textbox?

Comment: its quite famous third party control provider for winforms. And regarding question, you may not know this but others may know and thats why Infragistics tag was created in stackoverflow. And I have approached company for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_myTextTextBox.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.None;
```

After assigning border style, you need to do this.

```
_myTextTextBox.UseOsThemes = DefaultableBoolean.False;
```

I feel the solution is more generic and not specific to Infragistics. Thanks to Boris who guided me to this from Infragistics Inc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the MSDN??

[TextBoxBase.BorderStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.borderstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
this._myTextTextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

Comment: I think, MSDN hasn't anything about Infragistics controls